# How to get count of activities in an ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a use case wherein we need to identify the number of activities per pipeline.
We have more than 20 ADFs and within each ADF, we have more than 8 pipelines and currently we are having to check the count of activities manually as there was no REST API to get the Count of activities based on the below MSFT Docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactory?view=azps-6.3.0.

So is manual verification the only way or are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom powershell Module :
Install-Module -Name AzDataFactoryV2Activities

My Blog :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/identifying-the-count-of-activities-within-a-pipeline-in-an-azure-data-factory/
explains the scenario